# Floating action button code behavior based on navigation drawer selection kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, floating-action-button

I'm very new to Android development.  I have a project using the "out of the box" navigation drawer in Android Studio.  I'd like the FAB on the Main Activity to do different things based on what is selected in the navigation drawer - for example, from "Home" launch "Activity 1", "Gallery" launch "Activity 2", etc.

So far, I haven't found anything that does this, despite hours of Google research.

I'm using Android Studio 3.5.3 and kotlin version 1.3.61.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by "out of the box", you mean you just used the "New project" in android studio and made a navigation drawer activity.

If that's the case then in your `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` there would be a line of code setting the fab `onClickListener`. Inside that `onClickListener`, you can check the id of the `currentDestination` of the `navController` like so:

```
fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
    when (navController.currentDestination?.id) {
        R.id.nav_home -> doSomething()
        R.id.nav_gallery -> doSomethingElse()
        ...
    }
}
```

And you can do whatever action you want based on the current id.

Comment: That was exactly what I meant.  I knew it had to be something like that, but I just couldn't figure out what "item" I needed to "examine" to get the job done!  Thank you so much!!!